# How to pull the email address from a Facebook login?

Tags: php, android, mysql, facebook

My app allows people to Login with their Facebook Account to write comment, rate, and share as that user. My problem I am currently having is after they login, it just leaves a blank/empty field in my SQL Database so i can't pull their user id unless it is filled. Now is this a problem with my PHP or it's in my LoginActivity?

So I tried to add the permissions to my code and get the same response.

```
This is on my onCreate section.

Session session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(LoginActivity.this).setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.ONLY_ME).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email")).setCallback(statusCallback));
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
```

Comment: Do u want get email id of user from fb?

Comment: do you ask for the email permission?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

Do you configure your permission scope correctly?

Comment: Looked back at my code and swore I put it in! Its not there, so i will check it out and get back to you.